# Plot two graphs with different times on one graph

Tags: matlab, plot, sampling

I have two graphs, one is measurement (graph2), and one is result from the simulation (graph1). I need to plot them on one figure in Matlab but the problem is that graph1 has samples and graph2 has time value assigned to x-axis. How to make time from samples or samples from time to plot them on the same graph ?

[image]

This above picture is Graph1 and below is Graph2.

[image]

The time when they reach 0 is for:

graph1: x=3444

graph2: x=259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that one plot uses the *indices* to the samples as its `x`-values, wheras the other uses actual *times* as `x`-values.

You'll have to scale the `x`-axis to have both `x`-axes describe to the same quantity. I don't know the specifics of how you take samples, but here's a simple example:

```
figure(1), clf, hold on

% some example data
x1 = 0:0.1:2*pi;  
y1 = sin(x1);    

x2 = 0:numel(x1);    % add a bit of noise, just for kicks
y2 = sin(2*pi*x2/numel(x1)) + 0.02*randn(size(x2));    

% plot naively
subplot(1,2,1), hold on
plot(x1, y1, 'r')
plot(x2, y2, 'b')    

% plot w/ re-scaled x-axis
subplot(1,2,2), hold on
plot(x1, y1, 'r')

x2 = linspace(min(x2(:)), max(x1(:)), numel(x2));

plot(x2, y2, 'b')
```

Output:      [image: example output]

Again, the specific implementation of how you should re-scale your x-data depends on specifics of your experiment. You'll probably have to tinker a bit to get them to correspond.

Comment: This is great, only one thing is I don't know the expressions to y2 and y1 and cannot modify them. I only have two vectors... one going to 4401 and another going to 385. I have to "squeeze" the first one or lengthen the second one.

Comment: @Caslav: as long as the y-values correspond, it shouldn't be too different from what I've posted...